# Validation errors move button right - CSS

Tags: css

```css
.password-reset {
  padding: 40px 50px 0;
  float: left;
}
.form-field {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.form-field--wide {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-field label {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
.form-field input {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 245px;
  float: left;
}
.form-field input.error {
  color: #ed1b2e;
}
.form-field--half {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0;
}
.form-field--half input {
  width: 100%;
}
.form-field--repos {
  float: right;
}
.form-error {
  color: #ed1b2e;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 3px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.form-error.alert {
  clear: both;
}
.form-error ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.form-error li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.form-field--wide .form-error {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ed1b2e;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="password-reset">
  <form id="passwordReminderForm" action="/service/public/passwordReminder.do?siteLanguage=en" method="post">
    <div class="form-field form-field--half">
      <label for="user">Username</label>
      <div class="input error-input">
        <input id="passwordReminderFormUsername" name="username" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .form-field -->

    <div class="form-field form-field--half form-field--repos">
      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <div class="input error-input">
        <input style="width: 120%;" id="passwordReminderFormEmail" name="email" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .form-field -->
    <div class="verification-messages message--red">
      <div id="passwordReminderForm.errors" class="form-error">"E-mail" must be set
        <br>"Username" must be set</div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn--top-offset js-validate-image submit-form" value="Remind Me" type="submit">
    <input name="_csrf" value="7035c910-22bf-49b9-b0b3-facd9d460fbd" type="hidden">
  </form>
</div>
```

I have provided CSS and HTML code. As you see the problem is that  validation errors move "Remind me" button to the right, but it should always be on the left side. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions? I will provide button styles if needed. [link to fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/an04z337/)

Comment: The solution depends of your needs. There is 1 billion ways to do this, for example, using modal pop-up instead, or thinking of another layout, etc...

Comment: I don't want any pop-up I just want the button to stay on the left side

Comment: It should be always be *where* on the left side? Above the validation error messages, below them? To the left of them? Can you show a simple picture of the layout you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to first clear the left that is inherited and just apply float float left to the button using css here it is

```css
.form-submit-button{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn btn--top-offset js-validate-image submit-form form-submit-button" value="Remind Me" type="submit">
```

here is the js fiddle

**[Demo code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/an04z337/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Insert `<br style="clear: left;" />` before the button.

```css
.password-reset {
  padding: 40px 50px 0;
  float: left;
}
.form-field {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.form-field--wide {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-field label {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
.form-field input {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 245px;
  float: left;
}
.form-field input.error {
  color: #ed1b2e;
}
.form-field--half {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0;
}
.form-field--half input {
  width: 100%;
}
.form-field--repos {
  float: right;
}
.form-error {
  color: #ed1b2e;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 3px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.form-error.alert {
  clear: both;
}
.form-error ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.form-error li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.form-field--wide .form-error {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ed1b2e;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="password-reset">
  <form id="passwordReminderForm" action="/service/public/passwordReminder.do?siteLanguage=en" method="post">
    <div class="form-field form-field--half">
      <label for="user">Username</label>
      <div class="input error-input">
        <input id="passwordReminderFormUsername" name="username" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .form-field -->

    <div class="form-field form-field--half form-field--repos">
      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <div class="input error-input">
        <input style="width: 120%;" id="passwordReminderFormEmail" name="email" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .form-field -->
    <div class="verification-messages message--red">
      <div id="passwordReminderForm.errors" class="form-error">"E-mail" must be set
        <br>"Username" must be set</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
    <input class="btn btn--top-offset js-validate-image submit-form" value="Remind Me" type="submit">
    <input name="_csrf" value="7035c910-22bf-49b9-b0b3-facd9d460fbd" type="hidden">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above it could be achieved many ways,

you can do - move input button before message div

```
<div class="verification-messages message--red">
      <input class="btn btn--top-offset js-validate-image submit-form" value="Remind Me" type="submit">
      <div id="passwordReminderForm.errors" class="form-error">"E-mail" must be set
      <br>"Username" must be set</div>
</div>
```

or you can even play around using css float if you don't want to change the markup.

Comment: in your solution button will not be displayed when I will not have validation errors.